# DNS traffic keeps increasing

Tags: 14.04, dns

I have installed Monitorix on my home computer to play around with all these awesome things I can do with Ubuntu, and even joined the Monitorix mailing list. I had a question regarding how Ubuntu processes DNS requests after doing some research (and after the mailing list and google have not provided definate answers.)

I only have 2 ports open to outside traffic - both blocked in IP Tables and on my router - a non-standard SSH port is one of the main ones I use. Through this I am able to remotely access numerous services - Apache HTTPD, Tomcat, Stanbol, Monitorix, CUPS, etc etc etc.

The question I had here is inbound DNS is blocked and filtered out in my IP Tables configuration. For some reason, the outbound DNS requests my computer sends keeps increasing in a steady fashion - about a week ago my Inbound DNS was about 425 bytes/second, and right now it is around 700 bytes/second, and increasing.

A screenshot of the Monitorix page I am observing this is below. I do not believe this to be a bug in Monitorix as it appears valid based off IP Tables and packets hitting rules for Monitorix in IP Tables.

[image]

I was wondering if there is any logical reasoning for this to be occuring - as from what I have read Ubuntu does not do DNS caching, or maybe it does and I need to flush DNS cache or something.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by disabling DNSMasq using [this guide](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-disable-dnsmasq-in-ubuntu-12-04precise.html)

Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, for example

```
sudoedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

and comment out the line

```
dns=dnsmasq
```

so it says

```
#dns=dnsmasq
```

Save and exit the file and restart NetworkManager

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```